# Google android map at night?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

[image]

Hi all, My project requires a night mode map. But I can't find any other Google map type but satellite and street view. And I found out that [Big road](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigroad.ttb.android&hl=en) can do that. Can anybody help me come up with a solution?

Comment: No, accept 'rate'. You've asked a bunch of questions and not accepted any answers, and people who answer your questions would like to get some magic points. Go back to your old questions and tick the correct answers.

Comment: @tai.tran2008: sorry, I'm allergic to the word "urgent".